# Improper alignment of a textview

Tags: android, textview

Hello please look at this:

[image: this image]

I have designed this using following code

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_info_tv"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:maxLines="20"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_layout_bottom_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_us_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_top_margin" />
```

how to solve above problem?
please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: what you exactly want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Does not provide Justified aligntment of TextView By default.

You can use following library and achieve proper aligntment.

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

Answer (score 0):

Use following library to justify your text. This is under active development and will supports large text.

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android